# Silly TSQL Question - Taking (N) Characters in Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement where I want to take 100 characters from a field. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is some pseudo code below.

```
Select substring(0, 100, longField)
from myTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it. Use the [`SUBSTRING()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) method. This will work on any string/character/binary/image datatypes.

```
DECLARE @str varchar(1000);
SELECT @str = 'foobar-booz-baz-cowboys';

SELECT SUBSTRING (@str, 0, 10);   
-- returns foobar-boo

--from a table:  
SELECT SUBSTRING(CustomerName,0,100)
FROM   MyTable;
```

Comment: @Sam: sorry, you're incorrect. Both compile. I only included the 2 statements for backwards compat with 2005. Normally (2008+) it'd be `DECLARE @str varchar(1000) = 'foobar-booz-baz-cowboys';`

Comment: My apologies, I was not aware.

Comment: @Sam DeHaan: You might want to read articles on `SET` vs `SELECT` for variable assignment, too. It's almost always better to use `SELECT` when you can't use inline initialization (2K8+).

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudocode is pretty close.

```
select substring(longField, 0, 100)
from myTable
```

(Just for reference)

SQL Substring::

```
substring(expression, starting_pos, length)
```

Comment: Positions are numbered from 1, not from 0. 0 will work but, if I am not much mistaken (can't verify at the moment), with 0 you'll cut off one char less than the specified length.

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way is using [LEFT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx):**

```
SELECT
    LEFT(longField,100) AS longField, ...
    FROM myTable
    WHERE...
```